# How to pass a specific Parameter value to Jump to report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I have a report I created in Reporting Services using BIDS.  I have multiple text boxes that I have a Jump to assigned to go to the same report.  However, I want to be able to pass a specific parameter value to the query of the Jump to report to only display the specific data that the user clicked.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your are talking about but if you:

1.Right click the textbox you have that jumps to a report
2.Click texbox properties
3.Select the action tab
4. Enable as an action: choose go to report
5.  On specify report you can choose the report it is jumping to
6.  On the same window click add these parameters, choose the value the parameter is passing and the parameter (make sure the parameter exists in the other report first)
7. In the report that is being jumped to make sure the same selected value is being passed by the parameter.

Cheers!

Comment: The issue is that I do not know how to set the value for the parameter.

Comment: Set the value of the the paramter in Go To Window for the child report as the the name of the parameter in the Parent report.

Comment: But the issue is that the values would be different for each text box. Also, I have multiple values that need to be passed for one parameter.